# Latest node.js and latest now.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

Is the latest now.js 0.8 match to latest node v0.8.x?
Because last time i used it there were some errors at the begining about deprecated functions which started with ev_ or ef_ i dont remember right now. Anyway is it safe to use these versions together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess probably not.

NowJS v0.8.x was likely developed for NodeJS v0.6.x. The last release of NowJS was [in January](https://npmjs.org/package/now) (0.8.1) and the last commit was made [in April](https://github.com/Flotype/now/commit/957e7ac7f86ab60163dc5566653c186971f5ad09), while NodeJS v0.8.0 was released [in June](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/06/25/node-v0-8-0/).

The project also [appears to have been abandoned by the original team](https://github.com/Flotype/now/issues/208), who are [now developing](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nowjs/mF9WeWm0QPY) its apparent successor, [Bridge](https://www.getbridge.com/).

However, the underlying framework, [Socket.IO](https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io), still sees active development, with 0.9.10 being released earlier this month.

Comment: Bridge has been abandoned by its developers too, apparently. However, there is a fork of now.js that is being actively maintained (at least for now): https://github.com/jameskeane/knockout-now